# Как получить массив изображения с камеры в PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, opencv, qlabel, qtimer

Задача в том, чтобы получить массив изображения с веб-камеры, отфильтровать, выделить один цвет (например, только зеленый) и вывести в окно.

Это легко сделать с помощью *OpenCV*, но при использовании *PyQt5* возникает две проблемы:

1. Как получить массив изображения?
2. Как вывести измененное изображение в окно?

В представленном коде выводится оригинальное изображение с веб-камеры:

```py
import sys        
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):            
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)            
        self.viewfinder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera()            
        self.camera = QCamera(self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder)
        self.camera.setCaptureMode(QCamera.CaptureStillImage)
        self.layout.insertWidget(1, self.viewfinder)
        if self.camera.status() != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start()  
                        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self)
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("pyqt5")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

**Updated:**
Код для вывода зелёного цвета на изображении с помощью *OpenCV* представлен выше.

Необходимо вывести такое же изображение в окне *PyQt5*.

```py
    import cv2
    import numpy as np


    # Границы зеленого цвета в формате 'HLS'
    hls_min = np.array((30, 0, 0), np.uint8)
    hls_max = np.array((100, 255, 255), np.uint8)    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        # Трёхмерный массив оригинального изображения в формате 'BGR'
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # Перевод из 'bgr' в 'hls' (нужно именно в 'HLS')
        hls = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS) # Трёхмерный массив изображения в формате 'HLS'
        # Фильтр
        img_mask = cv2.inRange(hls, hls_min, hls_max)
        # Применение фильтра цвета
        img_filt = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = img_mask)
        a=cv2.waitKey(1)
        a=cv2.imshow("Filtered image", img_filt)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите как вашу задачу легко сделать с помощью OpenCV

Comment: @S. Nick добавил код с применением OpenCV, который выводит зеленый цвет на изображении с веб-камеры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен, что правильно понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать.

Вы пишите: "... необходимо вывести такое же изображение в окне PyQt5..."

Как вариант это может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import numpy as np
import cv2


class Ui_CameraPage(object):
    def setupUi(self, CameraPage):
        CameraPage.setObjectName("CameraPage")
        CameraPage.resize(640, 480)
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(CameraPage)
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(CameraPage) 
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(3, 3, 3, 3)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.cameraButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.cameraButton.setFont(font)
        self.cameraButton.setObjectName("cameraButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.cameraButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.cameraLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.cameraLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(480, 320))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.cameraLabel.setFont(font)
        self.cameraLabel.setObjectName("cameraLabel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.cameraLabel, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(CameraPage)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(CameraPage)

    def retranslateUi(self, CameraPage):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        CameraPage.setWindowTitle(_translate("CameraPage", "Camera Interface"))
        self.cameraButton.setText(_translate("CameraPage", "Camera On"))
        self.cameraLabel.setText(_translate("CameraPage", "Camera "))
        

class CameraPageWindow(QWidget, Ui_CameraPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # Границы зеленого цвета в формате 'HLS'
        self.hls_min = np.array((30, 0, 0), np.uint8)
        self.hls_max = np.array((100, 255, 255), np.uint8) 
        
        self.timer_camera = QTimer() 
        self.timer_camera.timeout.connect(self.show_camera)
        self.cameraButton.clicked.connect(self.slotCameraButton)

    def show_camera(self):
        flag, self.image = self.cap.read()
        
        if self.image is not None:
            show = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
            # Фильтр
            img_mask = cv2.inRange(show, self.hls_min, self.hls_max)
            img_filt = cv2.bitwise_and(self.image, self.image, mask=img_mask)
            showImage = QImage(
                img_filt.data, 
                img_filt.shape[1], img_filt.shape[0],
                QImage.Format_RGB888
            )
            self.cameraLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(showImage))
        else:
            self.timer_camera.stop()
            self.cameraButton.setText('Camera On')

    def slotCameraButton(self):
        if not self.timer_camera.isActive():
            self.openCamera()
        else:
            self.closeCamera()

    def openCamera(self):
    
# попробуйте так:              ----> vvvvvvvvvvvv <------ установите свое
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("mp4Video.mp4")
# или попробуйте так:
#        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        
        self.timer_camera.start(24)
        self.cameraButton.setText('Camera off')

    def closeCamera(self):
        self.timer_camera.stop()
        self.cap.release()
        self.cameraLabel.clear()
        self.cameraButton.setText('Camera On')

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CameraPageWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
# попробуйте так:              ----> vvvvvvvvvvvv <------ установите свое
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("mp4Video.mp4")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
# или попробуйте так:
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update:**

> а как интегрировать это в мой код? 
> Мой код большой и содержит много другого функционала,
> но структура выглядит как указано в первой примере кода в моём вопросе. 
> Ваш код отличается и не получается интегрировать его в свой

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import numpy as np
import cv2


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
#        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self)
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        # Границы зеленого цвета в формате 'HLS'
        self.hls_min = np.array((30, 0, 0), np.uint8)
        self.hls_max = np.array((100, 255, 255), np.uint8) 
        
        self.timer_camera = QTimer() 
        self.timer_camera.timeout.connect(self.show_camera)

        self.cameraLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.cameraLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(480, 320))        
        
        self.cameraButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Camera On")
        self.cameraButton.clicked.connect(self.slotCameraButton)
        
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.cameraLabel)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.cameraButton, alignment=Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignBottom)

    def show_camera(self):
        flag, self.image = self.cap.read()
        
        if self.image is not None:
            show = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
            # Фильтр
            img_mask = cv2.inRange(show, self.hls_min, self.hls_max)
            img_filt = cv2.bitwise_and(self.image, self.image, mask=img_mask)
            showImage = QImage(
                img_filt.data, 
                img_filt.shape[1], img_filt.shape[0],
                QImage.Format_RGB888
            )
            self.cameraLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(showImage))
        else:
            self.timer_camera.stop()
            self.cameraButton.setText('Camera On')

    def slotCameraButton(self):
        if not self.timer_camera.isActive():
            self.openCamera()
        else:
            self.closeCamera()

    def openCamera(self):
# попробуйте так:              ----> vvvvvvvvvvvv <------ установите свое
#        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("mp4Video.mp4")
# или попробуйте так:
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        
        self.timer_camera.start(24)
        self.cameraButton.setText('Camera off')

    def closeCamera(self):
        self.timer_camera.stop()
        self.cap.release()
        self.cameraLabel.clear()
        self.cameraButton.setText('Camera On')
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("pyqt5")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @bluesky что не так?

Comment: а как интегрировать это в мой код? Мой код большой и содержит много другого функционала, но структура выглядит как указано в первой примере кода в моём вопросе. Ваш код отличается и не получается интегрировать его в свой

Comment: @bluesky я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: всё супер! Благодарю!

Comment: @bluesky всего доброго. Удачи вам.